# ODBC Microsoft Query BMC Remedy SLM Status Table

Tags: odbc, remedy, microsoft-query

I want to use Microsoft Query to pull out stats on incident SLA status that can normally be seen in the SLM Status window. See the pictures below for reference.

However, I am struggling with finding the proper table to get the data from. What table is available to use as a ODBC data source for getting this information?

[[image: Incident window]

[image: SLM Staus Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are looking for is stored in the SLM:Measurement form.  You'll want the following fields:

```
SVTTitle (SVT Title) (300411500)
GoalCategoryChar (Incident Response Time) (300426800)
GoalTimeHr (Hours) (300396000)
GoalTimeMin (Min) (300451200)
GoalSchedCost (Cost Per Min) (301489500)
SVTDueDate (Due Date/Time) (300364900)
MeasurementStatus (Progress) (300365100)
ApplicationUserFriendlyID (Incident ID) (301238500)
```

From what I can tell, the "Next Target Date:" is calculated by Remedy when the SLM dialog is opened using the active links:
SLM:IntegrationDialog:OnLoadSelectTimeBasedTab_SetNextDueDate-Incident
SLM:IntegrationDialog:OnLoadSelectTimeBasedTab_SetNextDueDate-Change
SLM:IntegrationDialog:OnLoadSelectTimeBasedTab_SetNextDueDate-Request

It isn't stored in the table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! This helped solving my question completely. Thanks for your time and effort :)